# How to get all airports name list with code in Google Autocomplete place API

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to find only the Airport names in google place autocomplete API,
Actually, I'm trying to develop an app which needs to list airport names in the world on an android autocomplete text view. I m trying to use google places API. But couldn't do it. What is the best way to do this?

```
PlaceAutocompleteAdapter  adapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getContext(),mGoogleApiClient,
            BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY, null);
```

And In this time I'm Using `AutoCompleteFilter` is null but in the case of airport name what'll I Used